# How to reference Option_settings in Cloudformation for beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've written a CloudFormation for Elastic Beanstalk:

This is a part where I configure options_settings:

```
  EBVPCConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EBApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Configuration Template
      OptionSettings:
        # Define worker to deploy inside Mazda VPC
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: VPCId
          Value: !Ref VPC
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: Subnets
          Value: !Join [ ',', [ !Ref EC2PrivateSubnet1, !Ref EC2PrivateSubnet2 ] ]
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: ELBSubnets
          Value: !Join [ ',', [ !Ref ELBPublicSubnet1, !Ref ELBPublicSubnet2 ] ]
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: 0
          #Value: !Ref CachecontrolWorkerASGMin
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          #Value: !Ref CachecontrolWorkerASGMax
          Value: 1
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
          OptionName: LowerBreachScaleIncrement
          Value: -1
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
          OptionName: UpperBreachScaleIncrement
          Value: 1
  ...
```

Now I created a custom Alarm (want to scale on queue size) in the cloudformation:

```
  QueueDepthAlarmLow:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm if queue depth is less than 1 messages"
      Namespace: AWS/SQS
      MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
      Dimensions:
        - Name: QueueName
          Value: !GetAtt SQSQueue.QueueName
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 300
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
      AlarmActions: !Ref AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy
```

The issue is on the last line:

```
AlarmActions: !Ref AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy
```

I only found examples where this is referenced in .ebextension files or saved configs but not in CloudFormation. I don't want to use ebextensions or saved configs if possible.

How can I reference my AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy in CloudFormation?